# Creating 4 new csv columns using 2 columns of data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv with 4 columns and put it into pandas

```
username   likes  username2   likes2

Mill       2      John        10
John       3      Clyde       2 
Tye        7      Ellie       4
Clyde      8      Mill        9
Ellie      2      Ken         2
```

I am trying to create four new columns :

1. `username3` with a list of all users whose names are in `username` and `username2`.
2. `like3` with `likes` and `likes2` numbers for those users added up.
3. `username4` a list of users who only show up once in either list.
4. `likes4` with those users unchanged likes.

#### Desired output:

```
username   likes  username2   likes2  username3  likes3  username4  likes4

Mill       2      John        10      Mill       11      Tye        7
John       3      Clyde       2       John       13      Ken        2
Tye        7      Ellie       4       Clyde      10
Clyde      8      Mill        9       Ellie      6
Ellie      2      Ken         2
```

Comment: are there duplicates in column `username` or in column `username2`?

Comment: One approach could be to split the first csv into two DataFrames and do an inner and outer merge on each, then sum the likes, drop unneeded columns, and concatenate all of the dataframes.

Comment: `username` and `username2` don't have duplicates, they do have NaN's in the full data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is:

- Turn your usernames and likes and usernames2 and likes2 into 2 dictionaries of {username, likes} and {username2, likes2}
- Add the values of the matching keys, and the keys that don't match won't have anything added to them. Turn this into a new Series called `usernamesandlikes`.
- `usernameandlikes` contains all of the usernames and summed up likes for your remaining 4 columns, so all you need to do is filter them out into their respective columns using the `intersection` list for username3 and the `symmetric_difference` list for username4

The code to do this is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import collections, functools, operator 

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv")

usernameandlikes = pd.Series(dict(functools.reduce(operator.add, map(collections.Counter, [dict(zip(df["username"], df["likes"])),  dict(zip(df["username2"], df["likes2"]))])))).reset_index() 
usernameandlikes.columns = ["users", "likes"]

username3_likes3 = usernameandlikes.loc[usernameandlikes['users'].isin(list(set(df["username"]).intersection(set(df["username2"]))))].reset_index(drop=True)

username3_likes4 = usernameandlikes.loc[usernameandlikes['users'].isin(list(set(df["username"]).symmetric_difference(set(df["username2"]))))].reset_index(drop=True)

dfoutput = pd.concat([df, username3_likes3, username3_likes4], axis=1)
dfoutput.columns = ["username", "likes", "username2", "likes2", "username3", "likes3", "username4", "likes4"]

  username  likes username2  likes2 username3  likes3 username4  likes4
0     Mill      2      John      10      Mill    11.0       Tye     7.0
1     John      3     Clyde       2      John    13.0       Ken     2.0
2      Tye      7     Ellie       4     Clyde    10.0       NaN     NaN
3    Clyde      8      Mill       9     Ellie     6.0       NaN     NaN
4    Ellie      2       Ken       2       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
```

Comment: For the first line of code it keeps returning: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: what version of python are you on? I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: python3 I assume you are running the same

Comment: yeah, 3.8.2 - to be clear you are talking about the line after pd.read_csv() which builds the dictionary?

Comment: I'm running 3.7.7 - ah I had not changed input to df in my code. Now the first line of code after pd.read_csv is giving TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: i changed the var input to df on my end and tested it just now on a fresh python kernel